# What lemma for product of derivatives equals the n-derivative?

Tags: derivatives, fisher-information

Why must one require regularity in order for Fisher information to be $E\bigg( \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta^2} \bigg)$?

Rather than

$E\bigg( \frac{\partial l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta}^T \bigg)$

Since my notes say that "under sufficient regularity conditions", then:

$I(\theta)=E\bigg( \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta^2} \bigg)$

However, what's the lemma that says that the product equals 2nd derivative?

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you got something wrong here. Note that $$\frac{\partial^2 l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta^2} $$ is a second derivative, while $$\frac{\partial l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial l(\theta, X)}{\partial \theta}^T$$ is a product of two first-order derivatives. As such, they are surely not equal in general: consider for example the function $$l(\theta,X) = \theta \cdot X.$$

Try reading the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) on the Fisher information and compare it with your notes.

Comment: Then what's a lemma that says that they can be equal?

Comment: @mavavilj I wouldn't look for such a lemma (it would mean that $l$ has to satisfy a certain differential equation for all $X$, which is a very strict limitation), I'd rather try to understand what was meant in your notes. What is the definition of $l$?

Comment: The wikipedia says same as my notes: "If log f(x; θ) is twice differentiable with respect to θ, and under certain regularity conditions,[4] then the Fisher information may also be written as". But I want to know what the lemma is that allows for that equality.

Comment: Cramer-Rao bound? http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/inference.pdf (Theorem 1.1)